# In HttpModule with AuthorizeRequest event. when any request arrive I need to redirect to html page but i get IIS error with verb not supported

Tags: asp.net

Inside my authorizerequest event I have something like this:

```
public void authentication_request(Object sender, EventArgs e)          
{
    httpcontext.Rewritepath("~/ABC.html")
}
```

But I get IIS HTTP verb (POST) not supported. I know whats the cause, but dont know solution. The HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod value is POST thats the problem and its readonly. Hence can not change it to 'GET' before calling rewritepath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to rewrite path if anonymous user. It is not common to rewrite path for login page either.

Instead, we *cleanly* redirect to login page. *For example -*

```
public void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.Redirect(string.Format("/Account/Login?ReturnUrl={0}",
        context.Server.UrlEncode(context.Request.RawUrl)));
}
```